# How do quantum computers implement a random unitary gate?

Tags: quantum-gate, programming, experimental-realization

If I `from qiskit.quantum_info import random_unitary` and then `random_unitary(2**number_of_qubits)` What returns is a unitary matrix with dimension $(2^{number\_of\_qubits},2^{number\_of\_qubits})$, and if I stimulating the unitary operation on a classical computer it is matrix computation.

Here comes my question: what quantum computers do to implement this random unitary?

From the universality of quantum gate set, we know that an arbitrary single-qubit operation can be decomposed into the set of $\{H, S, T\}$ or $\hat U=\hat\Phi(\delta)\hat R_z(\alpha)\hat R_y(\theta)\hat R_z(\beta)$ where $\hat \Phi(\delta)=\begin{pmatrix}e^{i\delta}&0\\0&e^{i\delta}\end{pmatrix}$, $\hat R_z(\alpha)=\begin{pmatrix}e^{i\alpha/2}&0\\0&e^{-i\alpha/2}\end{pmatrix}$ and $\hat R_y(\theta)=\begin{pmatrix}cos\frac{\theta}{2}&sin\frac{\theta}{2}\\-sin\frac{\theta}{2}&cos\frac{\theta}{2}\end{pmatrix}$.

But when considering **physical realizations**, we need to consider the problem of finite precision and so on. Then, which method will the quantum computers adopt? And more generally, what if we introduce `CNOT` here to form the universal quantum gate set for an arbitrary number of qubits?

Even a great reference paper or detailed qiskit documentation can be helpful (in fact to make my work rigorous this is essential). I appreciate you in advance.

Comment: Actually, this might very well depend on what you intend to use the random unitary for. In most applications, it might be more practical to simply perform a random walk on a suitable universal gate set which converges (exponentially) fast to a random unitary with increasing depth. in many cases, an (approximate) unitary $t$-design might be enough, which is generally simpler to implement.

Comment: I am learning the quantum walk now(kind of confusing). Although gates like `CC...CC-U` can be implemented by $\Theta(n^2)$ basic operations, the `random_unitary(2**number_of_qubits)` no ansatz is known to me that __qiskit__ makes when writing the code, so this analysis is not rigorous enough for what I want to. So a most general analysis is my requirement(seems there are some exponential upper bounds).

Comment: And you are right, I need the result in case of the approximated unitary operation.

Comment: I'm still confused what you want to do. However, if I would run an experiment, and you want me to implement a ($n$-qubit) random unitary approximately, I would do a random walk on my gate set ... This is a braindead method and guaranteed to converge exponentially fast in diamond norm. And, there is no compiling needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In terms of decomposing an arbitrary unitary matrix on n-qubit system, this paper ["Quantum Circuits for Isometries"](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1501.06911.pdf) might be a helpful guide. As well as this paper: ["Introduction to UniversalQCompiler"](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1904.01072.pdf) which is implemented in the [UniversalQCompiler package for Mathematica](https://www-users.york.ac.uk/%7Erc973/UniversalQCompiler.html).

And how to implement single qubit and CNOT gates on hardware, i guess a good place to look at is the [Qiskit documentation on Openpulse](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2004.06755.pdf).

Comment: Thank you, the documentation seems good!